# Received different date&time formats in gmail imap headers

Tags: go, gmail, gmail-imap

Have used "github.com/emersion/go-imap" library in Go to fetch mails from the inbox.

However, noticed that I get two different mail-received dateTime formats:
1) 2019-08-12 09:06:21 +0000 UTC
2) 2019-08-12 02:05:11 -0700 -0700

Why is that?
I'm guessing Google alert mails have a different dateTime format in the headers than the normal mails. Not completely sure.

Comment: That's the same format, just different locations/timezones.

Comment: Understood. The difference in both is what I had to handle explicitly. That's why I was looking for a reason behind it.

Comment: Use [time.Time.Zone](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Zone) if you want to know the UTC offset. Use [time.Time.In](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In) to change the UTC offset.

Comment: I wanted to time.Parse() the email receive time. Since google mails have different layout than other mails, I had to parse twice with two different layouts.